# macbook pro 2011 13" doesn't detect external display

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, vga-adapter

I have a miniDP to VGA adapter, and its worked fine until this morning, I woke up and shook the mouse, but only the internal MacBook screen worked, not the external monitor. I tried to reset SMC and PRAM but it did not help. What might be wrong?

Comment: Did you disconnect the miniDP and reconnect it? Sometimes OSX loses track of it.

Comment: Have you tried the usual things to rule out the chance that it's a problem with your monitor? You can always make sure that everything's plugged in and turned on. If the monitor has a test function, you can try it to make sure that the monitor still works.

Comment: I tried diferent type and size monitors

Comment: @MartínMarconcini when I can't get peripherals to be recognized suddenly, I always: a) disconnect EVERYTHING I can (for laptops that is everything) b) reboot zapping the PRAM (hold down 'command-option-p-r' keys during boot up until you hear at least a second chime, which should be at/near maximum normal volume, screen brightness will also revert to default (on laptops). c) restart again, then connect periphs back up.